# SQL Server 2000 Personal Edition: SQL Query Analyzer is not appearing

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL server 2000 personal edition in my pc. I am now accessing it using windows authentication account. I can use the enterprise manager but when I try to access the sql query analyzer, there aint no window appearing for the query analyzer. Can someone help me on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds odd. Perhaps a re-install might be needed.

Could you clarify your meaning of "there aint no window appearing for the query analyzer". What type of window, the application window, or a query window?